# Return object from REST call PUT prints junk value

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest

I am trying to login using PUT method and in return expect some token. But the response I get prints junk values. The code block is as follows:

```
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
process.env['NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED'] = '0';

var client = new Client();

    var args = {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        data: data_text
    };

    var req = client.put("https://wesite.com/api/web/Logon", args, function (data, response) {
        // parsed response body as js object

        console.log(data);
        // raw response
        //console.log(response);
       // Status code
       console.log(response.statusCode);
    });

    req.on('requestTimeout', function (req) {
    console.log('request has expired');
    req.abort();
    });

    req.on('responseTimeout', function (res) {
    console.log('response has expired');

    });

    //it's usefull to handle request errors to avoid, for example, socket hang up errors on request timeouts
    req.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('request error', err);
    });
```

O/P I get is:

Finished in 0 seconds
Buffer 3c 3f 78 6d 6c 20 76 65 72 73 69 6f 6e 3d 22 31 2e 30 22 20 65 6e 63 6f
64 69 6e 67 3d 22 55 54 46 2d 38 22 20 73 74 61 6e 64 61 6c 6f 6e 65 3d 22 79 ..
. 
200

How do I get the return object and can print it in readable format? 
NOTE: JSON.stringify() doesn't help

Comment: Do you have code showing what the backend is sending?

Comment: Well, I am sorry. I don't have that piece of info. I have just started using node js a couple of days back. Can you pls suggest me a way to capture it?

Comment: what about documentation on the site in question? There is not enough information to know what the proper request should look like when going to the server in my opinion.

Comment: This the request what the server received:

<134>1 2016-08-30T14:39:24.052Z server100 REST - helloA0001 [hello.rest.servlet.util@2 ET="0.13" ETX="R0.13/W0/V0/C0" HM="PUT" HS="200" P="INFO" RH="9.79.176.67" S="1ead197c5ffb543f1db8a3d75af27926e28427b4" ST="2016-08-30T14:39:23.922Z" T="Liberty hello-thread-89308" U="user123" URI="/rest/api/web/Logon" XT="XT10010055"]